# How to deal with @Type on @AttributeOverrides

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Say you have an `@Embeddable` mapped like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class Wheel {
  @Column(name = "COLOR")
  @Type(type = "my.package.ColorUserType")
  private Color theColor;
}
```

and you try to use it like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Car {
  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverride(
    column = @Column(name = "STEERING_WHEEL_COLOR")
    name = "theColor"
  )
  private Wheel steeringWheel;
}
```

When I do this, I get a big, fat `org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: my.package.Color` on startup.

So is there a way to override the type or make sure it uses the defined type in the `@Embeddable` since it's obviously not being kept when the `@AttributeOverride` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this can't be done because it's not a `Basic` type mapping. Source: [Java 6 API - AttributeOverride](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html).

Answer (score 0):

Writing an `AttributeConverter` as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35758475/572380 solved my problem.