# How to override Enum field mapping in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I wanna remove code duplication on a legacy project. So I designed a base class like `IoeBase`.

But some subclass do not following the `EnumType.STRING`, they expected `EnumType.ORDINAL`.

How can I achieve the mapping override ?

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class IoeBase<E extends Enum> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2643992981146184972L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    // !!! THE PROBLEM !!!
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private E theValue;

   //...
}

@Entity
//
// @AttributeOverrides({
//        @AttributeOverride(name = "theValue", column = @Column(name = "theMm", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20)"))
// })
public class IoeInheri extends IoeBase<IoeEnum> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3629698185247120860L;

//// !!! I expected on this subclass !!!
//
//    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
//    private E theValue;

// ...
}
```

Comment: What is your point? What do you want to achieve? Do you want to access `theValue` field from `IoeBase` object? Or you just don't want to repeat mappings across all subclasses?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm refectoring a legacy project.  After refectoring, in base class, theValue filed are mapped as EnumType.STRING. Most subclass use this mapping, but one subclass used EnumType.ORDINAL mapping.

Answer (score 3):

`AttributeConverter` solves my problem.

Combining following knowledge

- this link http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/
- @Converts
- @AttributeOverrides

I can

- move duplicated code to base class
- map subclasses to its old table
- without change the database

in this legacy project.

---

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class IoeBase<E extends Enum> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2643992981146184972L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

//    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)  // do NOT specify mapping
    private E theValue;
// ...
}

//
// EnumType.ORDINAL -like mapping
//
@Entity
@Converts({
        @Convert(attributeName = "theValue", converter = IoeEnumOrdinalConverter.class)
})
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "theValue", column = @Column(name = "theMm", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20)", nullable = false))
})
public class IoeInheri extends IoeBase<IoeEnum> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3629698185247120860L;
}

//
// EnumType.STRING -like mapping
//
@Entity
@Converts({
        @Convert(attributeName = "theValue", converter = IoeEnumNameConverter.class)
})
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "theValue", column = @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)", nullable = false))
})
public class IoeInheriString extends IoeBase<IoeEnum> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4395231501780833765L;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// converter classes

@Converter
public class IoeEnumNameConverter implements AttributeConverter<IoeEnum, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(IoeEnum attribute) {
        return attribute.name();
    }

    @Override
    public IoeEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return IoeEnum.valueOf(dbData);
    }
}

@Converter
public class IoeEnumOrdinalConverter implements AttributeConverter<IoeEnum, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(IoeEnum attribute) {
        return attribute.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public IoeEnum convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        int index = dbData;
        return IoeEnum.values()[index];
    }
}
```